# Проблема при скоролинге коллекции swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

День добрый.

Возникла проблема: при быстром скролинге коллекции изображения перепрыгивают между ячейками проблема появляется не всегда. При повторном проскроливании изображения встают на положенные места и проблема с ячейками не повторяется.

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема

Comment: Неправильная асинхронная загрузка и т.д. Приведите ваш код, чтобы увидеть проблему.

Comment: спасибо за комментарий, была такая мысль, но все вылечилось банально обнулив все property  в методе prepareForReuse()